# How to change results cell padding in Azure Data Studio

Tags: configuration, azure-data-studio

In Azure Data Studio, I am trying to change the padding on the cells in the results grid.

According to the settings page, this is editable in the settings.json:

[image]

However, when I navigate to that file there is no mention of padding anywhere. Plus, searching online for the correct option to use gives no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe this helps:

https://github.com/real-napster/azuredatastudio_settings

...
sqlops_settings

My Azure Data Studio Settings

```
Settings
{
    "sql.messagesDefaultOpen": false,
    "mssql.intelliSense.lowerCaseSuggestions": true,
    "resultsGrid.fontSize": 12,
    "resultsGrid.fontFamily": "Microsoft Sans Serif",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
    "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 120,
    "resultsGrid.cellPadding": [  
        5,   !!!
        10,  !!!
        15   !!!
    ],
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "phase",
    "editor.smoothScrolling": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "files.autoGuessEncoding": true,
    "window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
    "editor.smoothScrolling": true,
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "smooth",
    "workbench.enablePreviewFeatures": true
}
```

marked the Padding entries using !!!

Comment: Thanks for the settings  @eagle275
I used the cell padding 1,1,1 with no !!!
looks fine :)